# Determinant of Jacobi of $C^3$ function

Tags: analysis, matrices

If I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that is $C^3$, then the elements of the Jacobian matrix is $C^2.$ Is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix also $C^2$?

Comment: Determinant is just a sum of products of the coefficients. So what do we know about sums and products of differentiable function?